# Hide elements until page is fully loaded

Tags: javascript, hide

I want a vanilla JS code that hides all page elements (except the loading spinner) untill page is fully loaded, and then deletes or hides the loading spinner element. My code does a good job at hiding the spinner once the page is loaded, but I couldn't accomplish the other part. It looks like this:

```js
function hideloader() {
  document.getElementById("loading").style.display="none";
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Title</title>
    <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body onload="hideloader()">
    <div id="loading">
      <!--All loading spinner design goes here-->
      Loading...
    </div>
    <header>
      <!--Header stuff-->
      <h1>My Title</h1>
    </header>
    <p>
      <!--Main content-->
      My content
     </p>
    <footer>
      <!--footer stuff-->
      Footer stuff
     </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, it's better not to do this, but instead to design the page so that progressive loading provides some content to the user while waiting for the rest of the page.

But doing it is quite easy: Just put your main content in an element (say, a `div`) that has a class on it (say, `hidden`), and remove that class when you want to show it:

CSS:

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

JavaScript when you're ready to show it:

```
document.getElementById("content").classList.remove("hidden");
```

(`classList` is supported by all modern browsers; if you need to support old browsers, it can be polyfilled or, to remove all classes, just do `.className = ""`.)

---

Another approach is to add a class to `body` when it's loaded, and then classes on the various elements you want to show/hide during load, with CSS like this:

```
body:not(loaded) .hide-for-load {
  display: none;
}
body.loaded .hide-after-load {
  display: none;
}
```

Then `.hide-for-load` elements are hidden until you add the class, and `.hide-after-load` elements are hidden when you add the clas.

Live Example derived from your page:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  document.body.classList.add("loaded");
}, 1000);
```

```css
body:not(.loaded) .hide-for-load {
  display: none;
}
body.loaded .hide-after-load {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="loading" class="hide-after-load">
  Loading<!--All loading spinner design goes here-->
</div>
<header class="hide-for-load">
  <!--Header stuff-->
  <h1>My Title</h1>
</header>
<p class="hide-for-load">
  <!--Main content-->
  My content
</p>
<footer class="hide-for-load">
  <!--footer stuff-->
  Footer stuff
</footer>
```

Comment: I tried the first method, but I think classList.remove("hidden") also deletes all the content in it, so I just replaced it with .style.display="none", and it worked!

Comment: @Cubetastic: *"I think classList.remove("hidden") also deletes all the content in it"* No, it doesn't delete anything. **All** it does is remove the class. If `.style.display = "none"` worked, you have your HTML setup quite differently than I was suggesting.